# Writing structured data to Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: json, hyperledger-fabric

Brand new to Hyperledger Fabric. I have been reading through the Hyperledger documentation, particularly the fabcar section:

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/write_first_app.html#updating-the-ledger

Whilst the example is setting attributes with primitive types and Strings, I was wondering if it was possible to pass in JSON objects to the Hyperledger (complete with JSON arrays), and would the world state be able to handle this and accordingly store it in couchDB?

Thanks,

Charlie

Comment: Hi! I just posted a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59359370/can-i-pass-objects-to-a-hyperledger-fabric-transaction . Had any luck finding a solution in the meantime?